# Duplicated UV Map changes the layout of the original

Tags: uv

I'm pretty new to blender and don't really know what I'm doing. I made a low-poly model and fully textured it, but I wanted to use a facial rig (the actual model is not rigged yet). I was going to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZYm4mg1Eyo) tutorial. At 7:12 he sizes a duplicated UV Map down to 0 and moves it off the screen, but when I try to do the same, my skin texture moves around because the original UV Map is also affected. I've attached images of what I mean. Could anyone explain what I need to do? Thanks.[image: what it's supposed to look like]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you move the UVs islands of the default UV map, of course it will move the projected image on the surface of the object, the *Image Texture* is projected according to this UV map. But in the tutorial he doesn't use the first UV map, he has created a second one, that won't be used for the body, only for the eyes. To use it you need to create an *Input > UV Map* node in your *Shader Editor*, select the map, and plug the node into the eye *Image Texture* node.

Example of setup, the 2 images (skin and eyes) are mixed through a *Mix Color* node, with the *Alpha* of the eye image as factor, this second image is projected by the second UV map:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering! When I set the nodes up like this my texture turns invisible in the _solid_ viewport shading, but is visible in the _material preview_ or _rendered_ shaders. And when I try painting onto the model in texture paint mode it gives me the error message of "Missing Textures, detected!". Is this normal? What could I do to fix this?

Comment: could you please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file?

Comment: In the N panel > Tool > Texture Slot > Mode, choose Material, or if you stay on Single Image, choose the right image